# ember data error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'user' record to this relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember model like this:

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    message: attr(),
    user: belongsTo('user'),
    inquiry: belongsTo('inquiry')
});
```

I want to createRecord like this:

```
var createMessage = this.store.createRecord('message', {
    'message': "test message",
    'user': 1,
    'inquiry': 1
});
createMessage.save();
```

I know this question has been asked several times but I can't find any clear solution. can someone please describe me why this error happening and what will be the solution.I am using  **Ember: 1.6.1 and Ember-data: 1.0.0-beta.5**

Comment: How do you know who user Id 1 is?  What's your long term goal, is my real question

Comment: may be this is the answer i am looking for. how can actually i passed user id?

Answer (score 0):

When I use `createRecord()` with relationships, I manually construct each of the objects.  There are a few different ways to do this:

For an example of adding elements to a `hasMany` relationship, see [Ember.js & Ember Data: How to create record with hasMany relationship when the parent and child don't exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983355/ember-js-ember-data-how-to-create-record-with-hasmany-relationship-when-the-p)

Or here's another example when dealing with a `belongsTo` relationship:

```
var message = this.store.createRecord('message');
var user = this.store.createRecord('user');
message.set('user', user);
```

Ultimately, Ember may **serialize** this `DS.Model` to only have a number for the id, but internally, it needs an actual link to an actual object.

**UPDATE: (credit to @[Craicerjackless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2618653/craicerjack))**

If the user does exist and you have the id:

```
 var user = this.store.find('user', 1).then(function(user){
    message.set('user, user);
});
```

This gets the user by the id "1" and then once the user has been found sets it as the user for the model.

Comment: I just received suggested edits, but there was no way to incorporate or approve them through SO. I manually added the edit and credited the author; if there's another way to handle that, please let me know!